# Angular directive not rendering correctly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an angular directive that isn't quite rendering correctly.

here's the html:

```
<cloud-login ng-repeat='c in ctrl.clouds' cloud="{{c}}"></cloud-login>
```

and the directive:

```
function CloudLoginDirective() {
  return {
  restrict: 'AE',
  template: '<a ng-click="ctrl.cloudLogin("{{cloud}}")"><img ng-src="../images/{{cloud}}.png"/></a>',
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    attrs.$observe('cloud', function(cloud) {
      scope.cloud = cloud;
    });
  }
 };
}
```

In my template, only the ng-src correctly populates with the appropriate text.

The ng-click does not.

Any hints?

Best.

Comment: ng-click="expression"   ng-src="string"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is due to the invalid expression caused by the `ng-click` expression: `<a ng-click="ctrl.cloudLogin("{{cloud}}")">` This results in syntax error due to all those mismatching or pre-maturely terminating quotes. `ng-click` takes an expression you don't have to interpolate it. Just do:

```
<a ng-click="ctrl.cloudLogin(cloud)">
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/xTNHhE?p=preview)**

You could also make your directive much simpler removing all those attribute watches and using isolated scope and function binding and decoupling `cloud` directive from its parent controller, like this:

```
.directive('cloudLogin', function CloudLoginDirective() {
  return {
  restrict: 'AE',
  scope:{
    cloud:"=", // Using a 2 way binding, if you need only text then just use @ combined with {{c}} when used
    onClick:"&" //Function binding
  },
  template: '<a ng-click="onClick({cloud: cloud})"><img ng-src="../images/{{cloud}}.png"/>{{cloud}}</a>'
 };
});
```

and

```
<cloud-login ng-repeat='c in ctrl.clouds' 
             cloud="c" 
             on-click="ctrl.cloudLogin(cloud)"></cloud-login>
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ncPr6X?p=preview)**